# Which is best to Use for creating a file from byte[]?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I want to create a file using byte[], which one is best.

```
byte[] content=File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\ServiceLog.txt");

FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\ServiceLog1.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
stream.Close();
```

or

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\12.txt",content);
```

Comment: Side note: when using `FileStream`, you should make sure you `Dispose()` it correctly, typically via `using`.

Comment: Its much more efficient to user WriteAllBytes, and its less code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a `byte[]`, you might as well just use `WriteAllBytes` and let the wrapper method worry about the rest. The `Stream` approach is useful when you are (oddly enough) *streaming* the data, meaning: you might not know it all when you start writing. Since you *do* have the `byte[]`, just us it. However, in the general case, note that `byte[]`-based APIs may have more impact on memory than `Stream`-based APIs, especially for large content.

Answer (score 11):

All your bytes are already in memory, so as well use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\12.txt",content);
```

Stream methods are useful when you are dealing with very large files, and don't want to keep everything in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was running into an insufficient resources error when using File.WriteAllBytes and was able to fix it by switching over to the Stream approach.